# Brute-force algorithm to find the set of all empty triangles

Tags: algorithm

Given a set P of points in the plane, specify a naive brute-force algorithm to find the set of all empty triangles with vertexes in P. (A triangle with vertexes a, b, c belong to P is empty if it contains no other point d which belongs to P.)

How shall I start solving this type of problem? Are there any existing algorithm which I should look up or you think I would have to sketch it out with a few points?

Comment: Perhaps reading the lecture notes - or even better attending the lectures

Comment: Thanks but I am not taking any algorithm modules. Just a book I read and the exercises come with no answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Given a set P of points in the plane, specify a naive brute-force
> algorithm to find the set of all empty triangles with vertexes in P.
> (A triangle with vertexes a, b, c belong to P is empty if it contains
> no other point d which belongs to P.)
>
> How shall I start solving this type of problem?

Well bottom up:

- For a single triangle and a single point, write a function *contains*, which tests, whether the point is in the triangle.
- For a single triangle and a group of points, look whether whether there is no point contained in the triangle. Call this *isEmpty*.
- For a group of triangles, test each.

Keywords are: iteration, predicate, filter.

- You should write tests on each stage, points in the triangle, outside, bordercases. Test as early as possible.
- Write testmethods, to make testing easy.
- Then Triangle.isEmpty or how this would look in your language.

Top down would work too. Then you might need mock-functions for testing. But I don't see advantages vs. bottom up.

Pseudocode:

```
Triangle.contains (p: Point) : Boolean ()

Triangle.isEmpty (ps: Pointset) : Boolean = 
    ps.forAll (p => ! t.contains (p))

triangleset.filter (t => t.isEmpty (pointset))
```

Comment: The runtime would be very bad, wouldn't' it?

Comment: @Harry: Title and description say: **specify a naive brute-force algorithm**. And senior performance coaches teach: First make it right, then make it fast.

Comment: Give me the code of a number of triangles and points, and I tell you, how fast it is.

Comment: How many triangles? For a rapid, testable prototype, you could start with an estimating algorithm, which only decides, whether a point p is in the enclosing rectangle, orthogonal to the coordinate system. From there you can refine the algorithm, if the geometric approach is a bit hard. I couldn't write it down from my head, but have an idea, how to test for being inside or outside. Ah - and maybe I couldn't use your code, because it might be in a language I don't know. :)

Answer (score 0):

Chose all possible combinations of a, b, c in P. With the rest of the points in P determine if they are inside the triangle.

I will leave that exercise to the reader - It is a bit of trigonometry

Comment: Probably the use of matrices would be useful. Rotation, and a stretch to make it an equal sided right angle triangle perhaps

Comment: Not sure about using matrices. I have little knowledge about algorithms.